# Как для текста внутри textbox сделать underline шрифт. Avalonia MVVM

Tags: c#, шрифты, textbox, avalonia, reactive

Возникла проблема с добавлением возможности сделать текст внутри TextBox подчеркнутым. В Textblock есть атрибут TextDecorations и он позволяет подчеркивать текст, но для textbox я не могу найти подходящего атрибута

Comment: Стандартный `TextBox` не имеет такой возможности.